# Reduce number of ajax calls in instant search

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am trying to make an instant search drop down for my site. All work fine, except for this.

```
var timeOut;
$('#search input[name=\'search\']').on('keyup', function(e) {
    // If enter - submit the search field
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('header input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').trigger('click');
    }
    // Call only when length is at least 2 and the key pressed is alphanumeric
    else if ($('#search input[name=\'search\']').val().length>2 && ((e.keyCode>=65 && e.keyCode<=90) || (e.keyCode>=97 && e.keyCode<=122))) {
        timeOut = null;
        //alert(timeOut);

        if (!timeOut) {
            timeOut = setTimeout(function() {
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'ajax.php',
                    type: 'post',
                    async: false,
                    data:  'ACTION=SEARCH&search='+$('#search input[name=\'search\']').val(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    beforeSend: function() {
                        $('#loader-icon').show();
                    },
                    complete: function() {
                        $('#loader-icon').hide();
                    },
                    success: function(json) {
                        //$('.product-list-row').html(json);
                        $('#search-listing').html(json['html']);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                timeOut = null;
            }, 500);
        }
    }
});
```

Problem 1: My script ends up making too many calls to the server, for some reason `setTimeOut` isn't working as I expected it to. Ajax call should only be made when the user has done typing or something like that and not at every key press.

Problem 2: For some reason when I type fast the input bar doesn't get edited. The ajax however works, but with the last textual input.

Comment: Try adding `clearTimeout(timeOut);` to clear the previous running timeout.

Comment: i didn't read the whole code, but the first major problem i saw is that `timeOut = null` does NOT cancel your current timeout, it just sets the reference variable to null. You have to call `clearTimeout(timeOut)` instead.

Comment: If I change it to `clearTimeout(timeOut)`, it stops working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of trying to tackle this with `setTimeout`, you can abort the previous call using the **[`jqXHR`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)** object returned by the AJAX. It is more clean and simple to use this. Remove `async: false,` too.

```
var timeOut;
var xhr;
$('#search input[name=\'search\']').on('keyup', function(e) {
    // If enter - submit the search field
    if (e.keyCode == 13) {
        $('header input[name=\'search\']').parent().find('button').trigger('click');
    }
    // Call only when length is at least 2 and the key pressed is alphanumeric
    else if ($('#search input[name=\'search\']').val().length>2 && ((e.keyCode>=65 && e.keyCode<=90) || (e.keyCode>=97 && e.keyCode<=122))) {
        if(xhr && xhr.readyState != 4){
            xhr.abort();
        }   
        xhr = $.ajax({
            url: 'ajax.php',
            type: 'post',
            data:  'ACTION=SEARCH&search='+$('#search input[name=\'search\']').val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            beforeSend: function() {
                $('#loader-icon').show();
            },
            complete: function() {
                $('#loader-icon').hide();
            },
            success: function(json) {
                //$('.product-list-row').html(json);
                $('#search-listing').html(json['html']);
            },
            error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Comment: Still doesn't stop multiple calls.

Comment: It works better than before. I'll accept an answer after I try the xxxmatko answer. Thanks.

Comment: As you said, it still does not stop multiple calls

Comment: @xxxmatko i am not sure what you mean.

Comment: Your answer can be still improved, because abhig10 also said that your solution will not stop multiple calls. It's a waist to trigger ajax call with every keyup, he should use the debounce method together with the ajax aborting. For instance if regular human types each 200 millisecond one character, you can set the debounce timeout to 200 milliseconds, it will save a lot of ajax calls, which are not needed.

Answer (score 2):

The right solution is combination of both, abort running request, if new one should be made, and also, tackle firing of the new request. You can use underscore library, which has nice function for that, called **debounce** (see http://underscorejs.org/#debounce) and your code should looks like this:

```
// This is your xhr, each request save into this 
// variable, in order to be able to abort it if needed
var xhr;

// Wrap your event handler using the debounce function
$("#search").on("keyup", _.debounce(function(e) {
   // Abort running request
   if(xhr) {
    xhr.abort();
    xhr = null;
  }

  // Store the new request
  xhr = $.ajax({
   // Search for the term $(this).val()
  });
},500));
```

There is no need to fire the search for each keyup, but only when user stopped typing - debounce will do it for you. And there is no need to handle previous results if the request should be made.